# How do I change the color of this typing indicator in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

How do I change the color of this typing indicator? (See image) I am using storyboard in Xcode and can't seem to figure out where I can change the indicator to black.

[image: Image indicator]

Comment: What became of this?

Comment: You answered it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `yourSearchBar.tintColor = .black` or whatever color you want to make it.

Apple's website has useful documentation. If you look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar), you'll find documentation about the object you're working on, which I believe is a UISearchBar.

The vars listed under "Display Attributes" are things about a UISearchBar that you can manipulate.

In this case, we're looking at the `tintColor`, which the documentation says applies to key elements of the search bar.